# Populating Object property asyncronously with angular2 observables?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular2-observables

I am trying to convert an angular2 component to use asynchronous data calls. I am displaying the data as on a chart using a dedicated charting library. The chart needs to b passed the data in a certain format (shown below).

```
public barChartData: any[] = [
    { data: this.dataService.getCellOEE('powders'), 
      label: 'OEE' }
];
```

The issue is that `this.dataService.getCellOEE('powders')` returns an observable. Which if I bind to the chart object like `[datasets]="(barChartData | async)"`, throws an error because obviously barChartData is an object rather than an observable.

How can I asynchronously populate part of my static object with the resolved Observable data and then bind that static object to the `datasets` property of my Chart UI component?

Comment: `barChartData[0]?.data `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like:

```
public barChartData: any[] = [
    { data: null, 
      label: 'OEE' }
];
this.dataService.getCellOEE('powders').subscribe(value => barChartData[0].data = value);
```